# Custom Page in Customer My Account Page - Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I Created a custom module. My requirement is to add new link after all links in Customer My Account. When click on that new link a new page should be shown.

**My Code is**

**Step 1**. Created new file in `app/etc/modules` named `Badge_page.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Badge_page>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Badge_page>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2**. Created new file in `app/code/local/Badge/Page/etc` named `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
                <Badge_Page>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                </Badge_Page>
        </modules>
    <blocks>
            <achievements>
         <achievements>Badge_Page_Block_Achievements</achievements>
            </achievements>
     </blocks>
        </global>
       <frontend>
                <routers>
                        <achievements>
                                <use>standard</use>
                                <args>
                                      <frontName>achievements</frontName>
                                      <module>Badge_Page</module>
                                </args>
                        </achievements>
                </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <achievements>
                      <file>achievements.xml</file>
                </achievements>
            </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

**Step 3**. Created Controller File `app/code/local/Badge/Page/controllers` named `IndexController.php`

```
<?php 
class Badge_Page_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout();
     $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Badges'));
    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Step 4**. Created Block File `app/code/local/Badge/Page/Block` named `Achievements.php`

```
<?php 

class Badge_Page_Block_Achievements extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public  function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        $this->setTemplate("page/badgepage.phtml");
    }
}
```

**Step 5**. And then Updated my `local.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/Package/template/layout`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
       <customer_account>
   <reference name='customer_account_navigation'>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
        <name>badgepage</name> 
        <path>achievements</path> 
        <label>My Badges</label></action> 
   </reference>

</customer_account>

    </layout>
```

**Step 6** Created `achievements.xml` file under `app/design/frontend/Package/template/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <achievements_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Badge Page</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/badgepage.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="achievements/index" name="page_content_heading" template="page/badgepage.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</achievements_index_index>

</layout>
```

**Step 7** Created `badgepage.phtml` under  `app/design/frontend/Package/template/badge/`

```
<?php echo "My Custom Module Output;"?>
```

Here I can see the link in My Account Dashboard But when I Click on it I was getting 404 Error.. Where am I going. Please Suggest me the Solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you Please Mark any answer as accepted from below which you found helpful or post your solution and mark it as accepted in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

**app/etc/modules** `Badge_Page.xml` and not `Badge_page.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Badge_Page>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Badge_Page>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I didn't see any changes in both codes anyways I replaced the code. But again same issue **404 ERROR** . I thought I did mistake **Step 5** Path <`path>badgepage</path>` . Can you correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Prince Answer, Also change your controller's action to

```
public function indexAction()
{
 $this->loadLayout();
 $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't worked for me. I thought  I did mistake **Step 5**  Path `<path>badgepage</path> ` . Can you correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Raghav in path node value try `achievements` instead of `badgepage`

Answer (score 0):

Was this question answered? I have the same.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194083)